# An equivalent theorem for compactness

Tags: general-topology

Prove:A space $X$ is compact if for any open set $U$ in $X$ and any collection of closed sets $\{K_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \lambda}$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}K_\alpha\subset U$ there exists a finite number of the $K_\alpha$'s whose intersection lies in $U$.

I believe one of the directions is a corollary of the following theorem: A space $X$ is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property has a nonempty intersection.

$(\Leftarrow)$
After receiving some good tips, I have now attempted this portion of the problem. Since $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}K_\alpha \subset U$, $X-U \subset X-\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}K_\alpha \implies X-U\subset \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}(X-U)$ so an open cover for $X$ is $\{U\} \cup \{X-K_\alpha|\alpha \in \lambda \}$. Then since there are a finite number of $K_\alpha$'s with $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}K_{\alpha_i} \subset U$, then $\{U\} \cup \{K_{\alpha_i}|i \in \{1,...n\}\}$ is a finite subcover of $X$ and $X$ is compact.

Comment: Using the [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-greengrocers-apostrophe-1690826) in mathematical formulas is not a good idea. As for the mathematics: if you replace the $K_a$ by their complements (which is what I though you meant by $K_a'$, $\ddot{\smile}$), then those complements and $U$ are a set of open sets that cover $X$ and you can take it from there (without using the finite intersection property).

Comment: @RobArthan hi Rob, I have attempted the backwards direction of the problem using your tips. Would you say it is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that looks good to me. (But you should still get rid of the greengrocer's apostrophe!)

Comment: @RobArthan any hints on how to approach the second direction? The book says one of these directions should be a corollary of the theorem I presented after the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the finite intersection property theorem to prove the forward ($\Rightarrow$) direction: apply its contrapositive to $\{K_\alpha\setminus U:\alpha\in\lambda\}$. You can also use it to prove the other ($\Leftarrow$) direction: take $\{K_\alpha:\alpha\in\lambda\}$ to be any family of closed sets with empty intersection, and take $U=\varnothing$.